# Spoofing IMEI numbers

Tags: imei

How does someone spoof a IMEI number on a android device? I have read about rooting the phone and stuff like that but can i do it without rooting? Any advice would be appreciated.
Right now i am leaning towards rooting the phone and then corrupting the EFS folder and making a backup of the EFS folder on another Android and restoring the target EFS folder from that backup if i am correct this should copy over the IMEI

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need root and without root, it's not possible

Xposed module [XPrivacyLua](https://repo.xposed.info/module/biz.bokhorst.xprivacy) is what I use. I have the pro version which IIRC is needed for spoofing. Non pro blocks access. There are many more such Xposed modules, you find in the repo. Play Store has also some apps that claims to do this but I have not tried them because they cannot be as effective as Xposed modules.

What you propose is a cumbersome, may (if you have identical devices) /may not work approach and not worth the effort

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer i will look into the suggested module i am trying to do this on a Samsung Note 10 do you have any information on how i can go about rooting this phone?

Comment: Also what do you mean by identical devices? Like the same phone type or what? Sorry just new to all of this

Comment: Also i looked into Xposed and i found IMEI Changer App is this legit or do i need to keep looking

Comment: If you are new, I suggest reading up [tag:rooting], [tag:EdXposed]. Click on them to read what it is all about and recommended questions. Please **don't** try anything before you fully understand. You have a Samsung device which is **not** friendly to such methods

Comment: Yeah i have been reading a lot recently and asking questions before i try anything with any Android device but i am also reading up on Samsung and how to properly root the device and stuff like that. One more question i was looking at the IMEI changer apps of Xposed and they all just spoof the IMEI to applications not the cellular network that's what i'm trying to learn how it is done